# How to write JUnit test cases with out passing arguments from test class

Tags: java, junit

I am new to Junit, and I do not understand how we have to cover the code below without passing arguments from test class. Can anyone suggest me please.

```
  public void process() {
        String message = "data";
        if (message != null && message.equalsIgnoreCase("data")) {
            System.out.println("print message"+message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("empty message"+message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: normally, you wouldn't have such a method. If message is a String received by a service call, you would mock that servicecall

Comment: In real life this method would either get deleted or refactored since the complete if-else-construct is obsolete. This method would either have a parameter or use a class member. Both could be set in a unit test.

Comment: You can't test this method with JUnit as written.  It takes in no arguments and returns nothing.  I would call it a bad design.  Pass in data and return a message - that you can test in many ways.

Comment: It will always print `print messagedata`. There's no need for this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JUnit `assertEquals` etc. methods, but only if your method returns something.

Nevertheless I don't see the problem here, as your method doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: the problem is he wants to check both the if and the else block. The code is just not sufficient to know what his actual code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
void test() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(bytestream));
    new Testing().process();
    assertEquals("print messagedata\r\n", new String(bytestream.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

However you can not test the else block since it can never be executed with `message` set to `"data"` from within your `process()`-method